# Need to replace character in a column range

Tags: notepad++

I'm using notepad++.  I have a very large file (1gb) that uses a pipe as the delimiter.  Unfortunately, there is a column in the file has data that also uses a pipe.  Is there a way to specify a column range (like 300-350) across a million rows that finds the pipe and replace it with a dash.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Notepad++ Multi editing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453151/notepad-multi-editing)

Comment: duplicate of <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453151/notepad-multi-editing>

Answer (score 0):

For very large files, use command line tools to parse the file.
For 1GB a visual editor for editing is counter productive.

The most popular tools for accomplishing your task is `awk`.

You can use `awk` in Bash shell after installing [GIT](https://git-scm.com/downloads).

My favorite Windows Bash shell alternative is [Mobaxterm](https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/download.html) free.

Or using the built in Bash shell in Windows 10.

If you post few sample rows from the large file, and post another question, contributors will assist you with `awk` as well.

Once you have text processing tools, the tool to extract the top 10 lines is `head`.

```
head largeFile.txt
```

There is also a `PowerShell` solution to extract the top few lines from a large file, in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10079572/powershell-equivalent-for-head-n-3).

Comment: I have to use notepad++ because im able to run it without actually installing anything. This works for one column  Find: ^.{300}\K|   Replace:-     However, i need to figure out how to increment to the next column 50 times.

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.{300}[^|]{0,50}+\K\|`  ( Adjust the values at your convenience )
- Replace with: `-`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^               # beginning of line
  .{300}        # 300 any character but newline
  [^|]{0,50}    # 0 up to 50 any character that is not a pipe
  \K            # forget all we have seen until this position
  \|            # a pipe
```

---

I've done a test with a smaller file, it replaces pipe with hyphen between the 13th and the 22nd column to show the method, adjust the values as you like:

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]